# Simulate painting black furniture - photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, painting

I have a black turtle tank (black wood) and I want to simulate what it would look like if we painted the wood a different color.

Original photo below
[image]

My attempt at doing it below
[image]

Any tips on how to do this?

Comment: It looks quite good to me! What in particular are you having issues with? Also, maybe explaining your process can be helpful for others, sharing what you've tried and why you are not happy with the result is always a plus.

Comment: I beleive what you need is the detail in this case it would be shadowing and possibly a little texture.  Painted wood usually shows its texture and with the grooves present I think a little shadow is in order.  It is hard to tell with the previous dark wood but I will look for some pictures to help explain what I am talking about.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make the colorize process a bit more natural we have to make sure that at least some of the furniture structure is preserved from the source image. Therefore it may be needed to obtain an image where the shadows are lit brighter than on the example here. This can e.g. be done by exposure bracketing, and combining layers with different exposures. We may alternatively try to use a flashlight to make sure the turtle tank is better lit for more details.

At present the details preserved in the image given are far from optimal, and also they suffer a lot from JPEG artifacts.

Let me below outline steps to colorize a single object.

1. Manually cut out the opject with a select tool.
2. Paste the object to new image in orded to adjust contrast, brightness, and color.
   *Be gentle with that. Less is often more to give natural results (below I already overdid it)*
3. Consider desaturation of the object before colorizing.

   [image]
   *<sup>Cut out, contrast optimized, and desaturized turtle tank</sup>*
4. Use your colorizing tool for desired colors.
5. Finally copy and paste the now contrast-optimized, and colorized object back to the source.

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

[image]

select the area using magictool which you want to change color

go to Adjustments
select hue/saturation
by adjusting adjust hue,saturation,lightness
you can change the color....

Comment: You can't adjust the hue of something that's black.. Nothing will happen!